# Understanding Dutch National flag Program

Tags: algorithm, partitioning

I was reading the [Dutch national flag problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem), but couldn't understand what the `low` and `high` arguments are in the `threeWayPartition` function in the C++ implementation.

If I assume them as min and max elements of the array to be sorted, then the `if` and `else if` statements doesn't makes any sense since `(data[i] < low)` and `(data[i] > high)` always returns zero.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`low` and `high` are the values you have defined to do the three-way partition i.e. to do a three-way partition you only need two values:

```
[bottom] <= low  < [middle] < high <= [top]
```

In the C++ program what you are moving are the positions where the partitions occurred. A step-by-step example:

```
data = [ 3, 1, 4, 9, 8, 2, 6, 9, 0 ]
low  = 4
high = 8
```

```
   [ 3 , 1 , 4 , 9 , 8 , 2 , 6 , 9 , 0 ]
p^  i^                                  q^
```

```
   [ 3 , 1 , 4 , 9 , 8 , 2 , 6 , 9 , 0 ]
    p^  i^                              q^
```

```
   [ 3 , 1 , 4 , 9 , 8 , 2 , 6 , 9 , 0 ]
        p^  i^                          q^
```

```
   [ 3 , 1 , 4 , 9 , 8 , 2 , 6 , 9 , 0 ]
        p^      i^                      q^
```

```
   [ 3 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 8 , 2 , 6 , 9 , 9 ]
        p^      i^                  q^
```

```
   [ 3 , 1 , 0 , 4 , 8 , 2 , 6 , 9 , 9 ]
            p^      i^              q^
```

```
   [ 3 , 1 , 0 , 4 , 9 , 2 , 6 , 8 , 9 ]
            p^      i^          q^
```

```
   [ 3 , 1 , 0 , 4 , 6 , 2 , 9 , 8 , 9 ]
            p^      i^      q^
```

```
   [ 3 , 1 , 0 , 4 , 6 , 2 , 9 , 8 , 9 ]
            p^          i^  q^
```

```
   [ 3 , 1 , 0 , 2 , 6 , 4 , 9 , 8 , 9 ]
                p^         iq^
```

As the algorithm says you:

- Swap the element ***above*** the bottom (i.e. `p + 1`) because everything below the bottom has been already checked, or
- Swap the element ***below*** the top (i.e.  `q - 1`) because everything above the top has been already checked, or
- ***Leave*** the element where it is because it belongs to middle.

You get `[3, 1, 0, 2]`, `[6, 4]` and `[9, 8, 9]` as bottom, middle and top partitions respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the lucid explanation.What should be low and high for this (2,1,0,0,1,2,1,0,2) ?

Comment: @abhi120: low = 1 and high = 2 will do. I think Alexander's inequality should be `[bottom] < low <= [middle] < high <= [top]` since 4 is given as low in the example but belongs to the middle partition in the final result (and the algorithm checks on `data[i] < low`).

Also note there's a (IMHO) [slightly simpler algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-an-array-of-0s-1s-and-2s/) (disregard the many utility functions and focus on `sort012()`) to sort a sequence of digits with exactly three distinct values.

Answer (score 1):

`} else if (data[i] >= high) {` shows that what you though you saw might not be what was written in the article.

Answer (score 0):

Think of `low` and `high` as the half-open range `[low,high)` for values in the middle partition. All values less than `low` end up in the left partition. The middle partition will contain the values from `low` up to, but not including, `high`. Finally, all values greater than or equal to `high` end up in the right partition.